# Setting up apache rewrite rule to only forward if in a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I currently have a site setup with the following in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
 ServerName testsite
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
 ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
 ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
 ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A1
 ExpiresByType text/javascript A1
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript

 DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/apache22/data/thesite/trunk

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule !\.(htc|js|tiff|gif|css|jpg|png|swf|ico|jar|html|doc|pdf|htm|xml)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../platform.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Where x.x.x.x is my IP.

At the moment it forwards anything which is not in the set (htc|js|tiff|gif|css|jpg|png|swf|ico|jar|html|doc|pdf|htm|xml) to platform.php

How htp://x.x.x.x/phpmyadmin to also forward. Would it be possible to only perform this rewrite conidtion if I am in a subdirectory. Eg. http://x.x.x.x/projectone
So htp://x.x.x.x/projectone/login would direct to the platform.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put your mod_rewrite directives inside a [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) or [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) container if you only want to apply them on a certain location or directory.

Comment: LocationMatch would probably be better suited in this case - the poster then wouldn't have to explicitly set the name of the location/directory, it could match any.

Comment: Location also supports regular expressions with `<Location ~ "/regex/">`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
RewriteRule ^.+/.+?/$ /platform.php
```

Note: I did not test this